# How to select data order by count rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to select data order by count rows

I want to select data order by count `media_user_action` rows, don't know how to do this in one query syntax

e.g
media_id 1 3 rows in media_user_action
media_id 2 1 row in media_user_action

return data
media_id 1 then media_id 2

```
SELECT
  m.*
  FROM media m 
  LEFT JOIN media_user_action mua ON mua.media_id = m.id

// ORDER BY COUNT(mua.*)  count rows desc ?
```

media

```
id | 
1
2
```

media_user_action

```
id | media_id | user_id | type
1  | 1        | 1       | 0
2  | 1        | 13      | 0
3  | 1        | 15      | 1
4  | 2        | 16      | 0
```

Comment: why downvote?  please let me know

Comment: I guess your question is unclear. You might want to explain it a little bit more.

Comment: question is not clear. can u explain more

Comment: thanks for reply I updated,  I want to select data and then order by count how many rows in media_user_action table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `COUNT` in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT m.id
FROM media m
LEFT JOIN media_user_action mua 
    ON mua.media_id = m.id
    AND mua.type = 0
GROUP BY m.id
ORDER BY COUNT(mua.id) DESC
```

---

If you want to add additional condition for `media_user_action`, add it in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT m.id
FROM media m
LEFT JOIN media_user_action mua 
    ON mua.media_id = m.id
GROUP BY m.id
ORDER BY COUNT(mua.id) DESC
```

Comment: thanks for reply, what is ` GROUP BY <list all columns of media here>` what's in < > ?? and do you mean I have to use group by if I want to use count in order ?

Comment: Replace that with all columns of `media`. See my update.

Comment: what if I want to count where type = 0 where should I put type = 0